# windows 8 Launch the default media player for metro style application

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have hosted a video file (uri=http://testserver/test.mp4) in the webserver and i want to load the file in the default media player in the through my metro style application. i have tried the 
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchURIAsyc(uri),
since the protocol used is http,  the  file loads in the IE.
i am looking for something analogous to MediaPlayerLauncher for Wp7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Audio Streaming in Windows8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832520/audio-streaming-in-windows8)

Comment: Are you saying you want to play this *outside* of your application? Or in it?

Comment: I think this is a good question and not a duplicate. I could not find any solution to it though. Perhaps something like an asx file could be used, but checking the ZuneVideo app's AppManifest.xml I can't see it as a listed file association. I'm guessing this might not be supported yet, but something worth relaying to the team working on the video app. I have similar issues with composing a formatted email.

Comment: @DominicHopton i dont want to use an mediaelement , instead i want to launch an external default media player application present in  windows8(windows media player), and i want to play the video outside my application..

Comment: I dont think this is possible, because the default handler for HTTP is IE. The inbox metro video app doesn't support streaming in this fashion, so you I think you are either going to have to create a separate application, or play using a media element. Why don't you want to use a <video> tag?

Comment: that's my last resort thanks guys...